# looping array to match group membership

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm in the process of trying to setup a script that get the context of a user on form submit, takes the user ID (email), searches a spreadsheet to locate the user, and then find the manager's email that the user is associated with.  Below is some code i've been developing and I'm able to grab the data from the spreadsheet and create an array and loop over it.  What I'm wondering if anyone could help provide suggestions on the best way to structure the spreadsheet to search and locate membership and then how to do that in the script.

```
function getUser() {
 //Uses the base class to get acive user's email
   var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
 //Uses the UserManager class to get info by passing in the getActive user from base class
   var userFirst = UserManager.getUser(Session.getActiveUser()).getGivenName();
   var userLast = UserManager.getUser(Session.getActiveUser()).getFamilyName();
 //Go to View then Log to see results
 return email;
 }

//Function used to look up manager of user submitting PTO request
function getManager() {
  var requestor = getUser();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var manager = ss.getSheetByName('Managers');
  var values = manager.getDataRange().getValues();

  for ( i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var obj = values[i];
    Logger.log(obj);
    for (var j in obj) {
    var value = obj[j];
     //Logger.log(value);
      if (value == requestor){
       Logger.log(value);
      }
    }
```

I started to thinking have a user list on one sheet and managers on another but wasn't sold on that, as I wasn't sure how to tie the user to a manager.  Then thought maybe three columns, each column starts with a manager and each row below the manager's name users names?

I'd like the script to avoid hard coding values.  Any thought or suggestion to spark ideas is so welcome.

thanks

**UPDATED**
Ok, so I've worked on the code and now have three functions running.  I've also decided to go with using a spreadsheet with two sheets, one for managers and one for employees.  The sheets for each are similar.  Three columns (Name, email, groupID)  The group ID for the employee will match the groupID of a manager to whom that employee belongs. Here is the updated code:  getUser() will get the active user, findEmployee() uses getUser to get email then matches it and returns groupID.  getMnger() uses the groupID to find managers email.

I'm not sure this is the best way but I'm also learning teaching myself. (only get to play around here and there

```
function getUser() {
 //Uses the base class to get acive user's email
   var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
 //Uses the UserManager class to get info by passing in the getActive user from base class
   var userFirst = UserManager.getUser(Session.getActiveUser()).getGivenName();
   var userLast = UserManager.getUser(Session.getActiveUser()).getFamilyName();
 //Go to View then Log to see results
   return email;
 }

function findEmployee() {
  //Gets the active Spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //Gets the sheet by name
  var employee = ss.getSheetByName('Roster');
  //get the values in sheet
  var values = employee.getDataRange().getValues();
  // makes a call to function getUser() to return email of active user
  var user = getUser();
  // loops over data values, matches to active user email, returns group ID
  for (var i=0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j < values[i].length; j++) {     
      if ( values[i][j] == user) {
       return values[i][2];
       //used to verify / debug
       Logger.log(values[i][2]);
    }
   }
  }
 }

function getMnger(){
  //Gets current spreadsheet and locates the managers sheet and grabs the data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var manager = ss.getSheetByName('Managers');
  var values = manager.getDataRange().getValues();
  var groupID = findEmployee();

  //Loops over the data creating associative array
  for (var i=0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      if ( values[i][j] == groupID) {
        //Used to debug and verify
          Logger.log(values[i][1]);
        return values[i][1];
    }      
   }     
  } 
 }
```

This is a work in progress.  Anyone have thoughts so far on ?  My biggest question now is how to return the value I want based on another value.  In both findEmployee() and getMnger(), once it matches it returns a hard coded index in values[][].  i.e. return values[i][1]; OR return values[i][2];

Is there a way to ensure that hardcode values are not needed here?  Basically i'm looking to take the users and find him in a column on a sheet and then return the corresponding groupID in another column beside his email.  Make sense?

thanks!

Comment: are you looking for something to "view" or something to "search in" with a script ? In the second case scriptdB would probably be a better approach, each user would have ' "linked manager" property easily searchable

Comment: The idea is, users will hit a Google Form to request Paid-time-off (PTO).  They will select two field, a starting date and end date and then submit.  From here the rest of the work is done by the script.  the script will find out who submitted it (all users in the same domain).  Once the script knows the user (getUser function) it will look for who the manager is for that user.   This will allow the script to then start email notifications for approval of PTO.

Comment: Ok.. I think I've figure out what I wanted here for looping and identifying and I think it's shown in the updated code above.  Anyone can clarify or let me know if wrong.  Do to Session.getActiveUser() not working on Google form i'm moving to writing a UIApp to handle this.  I'm sure I'll be posting about it..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` within the spreadsheet.  And since you'd like to avoid hard coding values, you can create two sheets, one for managers and one for users, assign each manager with a unique key, and then for each user in the user list sheet, include the unique manager key corresponding to their managers.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.. That is possible, just need to start working on how to match the unq. key column along with the name.

Comment: `indirect` can match the keys between spreadsheets, i.e. assuming the manager's sheet is called "Managers" and you are lookking at the unique id from column J row 3: `=INDIRECT("Managers!A"&J3)`