# GAS execute under the content of active user

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Is it possible to use a Google form, develop a GAS script that executes on form submission but have it run under the context of the users submitting the form?

Users will be in a GApps for Business domain?

Will it need to be published as a web app using doGet(), even though there will be no UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only webApps have the ability to run under user's authority and they have an authorization request feature to handle that case. A form has no way to ask for authorization so it won't be able to do anything (or to trigger a script that would do anything) in the name of a user without explicit permission. That's a basic security case and hopefully there will be no way to go around it.

I guess the only way to get what you want would be to create the form with UiApp or HTML Service and deploy it as a webapp running under user's authority, in that case your users will be asked for authorization to access the services you need.

note : you said "*even though there will be no UI?*" but the form itself is a Ui isn't it ?...

Comment: Thanks Serge.  Poor choice of words saying no UI.  Meant that I wouldn't be writing the UI code.  Doing a UIApp wouldn't be that hard, I believe to accomplish what I'm looking to do.  It may actually make things easier for me.  This question was based on what I'm running into for this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310501/looping-array-to-match-group-membership)